# Can't Deploy Asp.net core 2.0 with React Project

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, hosting

I made a website with Asp.net ReactJs project. It was working on local but when i want to deploy on my host its getting errors. I cant find much things on the net. 
I think im making mistake installing wrong place or missing some adjustment but no idea. Here is my steps

**1- I set the 'homepage' in package.json but no idea what to do**
[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6hU7.png)

**2- I fill the 'site path' = wwwroot and some other things but not work**
[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm3wY.png)

**3- Its getting succesfully upload at host and here it file structure in hosting page** [Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXfMa.png) - [Fourth Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr7R2.png)

**4- and its getting now http error 502.5 before that it was http error 500 now 502.5** [Last Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA2Y3.png)

Its like dont know where is the main page location.